# What are the cases in general which require template argument to be complete?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider simple code :

```
struct x;
template<typename> void func(){}

int main() {
    func<x>();
    return 0;
}
```

This above code doesn't requires class `x` to be complete, are there any other cases which don't require `x` to be complete? . Also in general what are the cases which require template argument to be complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template argument must be a complete type if some template instantiation causes code to be generated which requires the type to be complete, e.g. any construct requiring the size of template the argument, use of member access, etc.

In your case, the template parameter is not used at all. No instantiations will require the type to be complete. We can cause an error very easily:

```
struct x;

template<typename T> void func()
{ T a; } //requires complete type

int main() {
    func<x>();
}
```

GCC says:

> error: 'x a' has incomplete type

If we used a pointer or a reference, a complete type wouldn't be necessary:

```
template<typename T> void func()
{ T* a; } //does not need complete type
```

Note that the type needs to be complete at *instantiation time*. This means that so long as you define the struct between the use in the template and the instantiation of that template, you're okay. This compiles cleanly:

```
struct x;

template<typename T> void func()
{ T a; } //requires complete type

struct x{}; //we now define x

int main() {
    func<x>(); //instantiation
}
```

---

Note that member functions of a template class are only instantiated when they are used. As such, you can use a template class which has member functions requiring complete types with an incomplete template parameter, so long as you don't use those member functions.

For example, with this code:

```
struct x;

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void bar() {
    }

    void baz() {
        T a;   
    }
};
```

This is valid:

```
Foo<x> a;
a.bar();
```

But this is not:

```
Foo<x> a;
a.baz(); //requires complete type
```

Answer (score 3):

Requiring `x` to be complete is any situation where you need to know how `x` is laid out in memory. For example:

```
struct x;
template<typename> void func() {
    // Compiler error: what is x::foo ???
    std::cout << x.foo() << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    func<x>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For clarification: if `struct x` is defined between `func()` definition and the `main()` function, this works.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as everywhere else: You can use an incomplete type if

- You only use pointers to the type
- or references
- or use it as a parameter in a declaration

without using the pointer/reference to access members.